# @Cacheable use SpEL for 'value' filed?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-el

Here is a code snippet:

```
  @Cacheable(value = "employee", key = "#surname")
  public Person findEmployeeBySurname(String firstName, 
        String surname, int age) {
     return new Person(firstName, surname, age);
  }
```

It looks like '**key**' filed supports SpEL, I was wondering is it possible to use SpEL in the '**value**' field? The reason is- I don't want to hardcode the 'cache name' inside @**Cacheable** but, also 'value' doesn't support to load the cache name from property or using Apache Common Configuration. So, I was just looking for is there any way I can avoid hardcoding the 'cache name' and use SpEL.  TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 4.1, you can try using `CacheResolver`. See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/06/16/further-cache-improvements-in-spring-4-1).

> One of the nicest features we found in JSR-107 was the ability to
>   resolve the cache to use at runtime, that is based on the actual
>   method execution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this which may or may not help in the original question. It doesn't fully evaluate SpEL but you can access parameters by their index:

```java
@Bean("methodParameterIndexCacheResolver")
public MethodParameterIndexCacheResolver customCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return new MethodParameterIndexCacheResolver(cacheManager);
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationInvocationContext;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheResolver;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.ParserContext;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public class MethodParameterIndexCacheResolver extends SimpleCacheResolver {

    private static final ExpressionParser PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();

    protected MethodParameterIndexCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        super(cacheManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
        return context.getOperation().getCacheNames().stream()
                .map(it -> PARSER.parseExpression(it, ParserContext.TEMPLATE_EXPRESSION)
                        .getValue(new StandardEvaluationContext(context.getArgs()), String.class))
                .toList();
    }
}
```

```java
@Cacheable(value = "cachedMethodName-#{[0]}-#{[1].toEpochDay()}", cacheResolver = "methodParameterIndexCacheResolver")
public Other cachedMethod(String foo, 
        LocalDate bar, int other, String params) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).